# How can I cast a class to an interface with a matching method signature in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, operators, extension-methods

Let's say we have an interface `IFoo` that defines a single method with the signature: `public void Bar()`. We also have a class `Baz` that defines multiple methods, one of which has the same exact signature as `IFoo.Bar`. `Baz` does not implement `IFoo` and it cannot be edited directly (we can only add extensions). If we have an array `IFoo[]` that we want to iterate over and call the `Bar` method of each item, we could add any concrete class that implements `IFoo`. I'd like to also add `Baz` objects to this array as well. Ideally we could simply cast `Bar` to `IFoo` but the cast needs to be defined. So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to write a conversion operator to cast `Baz` to `IFoo`?
2. Is it possible to defined this conversion operator as an extension of `Baz`?

Thank you.

I tried casting `Baz` to `IFoo` hoping that since they both contain identical `Bar` method signatures and `IFoo` does not implement any properties or methods not defined in `Baz`, they would be implicitly compatible. This led to [Compiler Error CS0030](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0030?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0030)). My current work around is to have two arrays one `IFoo[]` and one `Baz[]`. For project specific reasons this is not ideal.

Comment: `class FooImplementingBaz : Baz, IFoo {}` should do the job. You can also build a wrapper class that wraps an existing `Baz` instance and implements `IFoo`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It may not be viable with my particular requirements but that is a good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a wrapper class that implements `IFoo` and wraps a `Baz` instance. Together with an extension it is very userfriendly.

```cs
public static class BazExtensions
{
    class FooWrapper : IFoo
    {
        private readonly Baz _baz;
        public FooWrapper(Baz baz)
        {
            _baz = baz;
        }
        
        void IFoo.Bar() => _baz.Bar();
    }
    
    public static IFoo AsIFoo(this Baz baz) => new FooWrapper(baz);
}
```

To get from `Baz[]` to `IFoo[]` you use Linq

```cs
IFoo[] fooArray = bazArray.Select(b => b.AsIFoo()).ToArray();
```

[example on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RC8y9d)